# Android gallery open in a specific image

Tags: android, gridview, gallery

Hi developing an image album using the android gallery and gridview tutorials I want when i click an image in the gridview the gallery activity at the position of the clicked image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If im right u need to go to the particular image in the gallery using its position then u can use this code.

```
galleryObject.setSelection(imagePosition, true);
```

This code will go the particular position in the gallery.